# kube-proxy not working for service cluster IPs

Tags: kubernetes

I installed a k8s 1.23.3 cluster on four raspberry pi's running raspberrypi OS 11 (bullseye) [arm64](https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-64-bit); mostly by following [this guide](https://opensource.com/article/20/6/kubernetes-raspberry-pi).
The gist of it is that the control plane was created using this command

```
kubeadm init --token={some_token} --kubernetes-version=v1.23.3 --pod-network-cidr=10.1.0.0/16 --service-cidr=10.11.0.0/16 --control-plane-endpoint=10.0.4.16 --node-name=rpi-1-1
```

I then created my own `kube-verify` namespace, put a deployment of the [echo-server](https://hub.docker.com/r/ealen/echo-server) into it, and created a service for it.

However, **I cannot reach the service's cluster IP from any of the nodes. *Why?*** Requests simply time out, while requests to the pod's cluster IP work fine.
I suspect my `kube-proxy` is not working as it should. Below is what I investigated so far.

```
$ kubectl get services -n kube-verify -o=wide

NAME          TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE   SELECTOR
echo-server   ClusterIP   10.11.213.180   <none>        8080/TCP   24h   app=echo-server
```

```
$ kubectl get pods -n kube-system -o=wide

NAME                              READY   STATUS    RESTARTS      AGE   IP          NODE      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
coredns-64897985d-47gpr           1/1     Running   1 (69m ago)   41h   10.1.0.5    rpi-1-1   <none>           <none>
coredns-64897985d-nf55w           1/1     Running   1 (69m ago)   41h   10.1.0.4    rpi-1-1   <none>           <none>
etcd-rpi-1-1                      1/1     Running   2 (69m ago)   41h   10.0.4.16   rpi-1-1   <none>           <none>
kube-apiserver-rpi-1-1            1/1     Running   2 (69m ago)   41h   10.0.4.16   rpi-1-1   <none>           <none>
kube-controller-manager-rpi-1-1   1/1     Running   2 (69m ago)   41h   10.0.4.16   rpi-1-1   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-5467m             1/1     Running   1 (69m ago)   28h   10.0.4.17   rpi-1-2   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-7wpvz             1/1     Running   1 (69m ago)   28h   10.0.4.18   rpi-1-3   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-9chxk             1/1     Running   1 (69m ago)   28h   10.0.4.19   rpi-1-4   <none>           <none>
kube-flannel-ds-x5rvx             1/1     Running   1 (69m ago)   29h   10.0.4.16   rpi-1-1   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-8bbjn                  1/1     Running   1 (69m ago)   28h   10.0.4.17   rpi-1-2   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-dw45d                  1/1     Running   1 (69m ago)   28h   10.0.4.18   rpi-1-3   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-gkkxq                  1/1     Running   2 (69m ago)   41h   10.0.4.16   rpi-1-1   <none>           <none>
kube-proxy-ntl5w                  1/1     Running   1 (69m ago)   28h   10.0.4.19   rpi-1-4   <none>           <none>
kube-scheduler-rpi-1-1            1/1     Running   2 (69m ago)   41h   10.0.4.16   rpi-1-1   <none>           <none>
```

```
$ kubectl logs kube-proxy-gkkxq -n kube-system

I0220 13:52:02.281289       1 node.go:163] Successfully retrieved node IP: 10.0.4.16
I0220 13:52:02.281535       1 server_others.go:138] "Detected node IP" address="10.0.4.16"
I0220 13:52:02.281610       1 server_others.go:561] "Unknown proxy mode, assuming iptables proxy" proxyMode=""
I0220 13:52:02.604880       1 server_others.go:206] "Using iptables Proxier"
I0220 13:52:02.604966       1 server_others.go:213] "kube-proxy running in dual-stack mode" ipFamily=IPv4
I0220 13:52:02.605026       1 server_others.go:214] "Creating dualStackProxier for iptables"
I0220 13:52:02.605151       1 server_others.go:491] "Detect-local-mode set to ClusterCIDR, but no IPv6 cluster CIDR defined, , defaulting to no-op detect-local for IPv6"
I0220 13:52:02.606905       1 server.go:656] "Version info" version="v1.23.3"
W0220 13:52:02.614777       1 sysinfo.go:203] Nodes topology is not available, providing CPU topology
I0220 13:52:02.619535       1 conntrack.go:52] "Setting nf_conntrack_max" nf_conntrack_max=131072
I0220 13:52:02.620869       1 conntrack.go:100] "Set sysctl" entry="net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_tcp_timeout_close_wait" value=3600
I0220 13:52:02.660947       1 config.go:317] "Starting service config controller"
I0220 13:52:02.661015       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for service config
I0220 13:52:02.662669       1 config.go:226] "Starting endpoint slice config controller"
I0220 13:52:02.662726       1 shared_informer.go:240] Waiting for caches to sync for endpoint slice config
I0220 13:52:02.762734       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for service config 
I0220 13:52:02.762834       1 shared_informer.go:247] Caches are synced for endpoint slice config
```

**What I'm noticing here is that the `Nodes topology is not available`**, so I dug into the kube-proxy config some more, but nothing stands out to me.
If there is indeed an issue with the nodes topology in my cluster, please direct me towards some resources on how to troubleshoot this, as I could not find anything meaningful based on this error message.

```
$ kubectl describe configmap kube-proxy -n kube-system

Name:         kube-proxy
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       app=kube-proxy
Annotations:  kubeadm.kubernetes.io/component-config.hash: sha256:edce433d45f2ed3a58ee400690184ad033594e8275fdbf52e9c8c852caa7124d

Data
====
config.conf:
----
apiVersion: kubeproxy.config.k8s.io/v1alpha1
bindAddress: 0.0.0.0
bindAddressHardFail: false
clientConnection:
  acceptContentTypes: ""
  burst: 0
  contentType: ""
  kubeconfig: /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig.conf
  qps: 0
clusterCIDR: 10.1.0.0/16
configSyncPeriod: 0s
conntrack:
  maxPerCore: null
  min: null
  tcpCloseWaitTimeout: null
  tcpEstablishedTimeout: null
detectLocalMode: ""
enableProfiling: false
healthzBindAddress: ""
hostnameOverride: ""
iptables:
  masqueradeAll: false
  masqueradeBit: null
  minSyncPeriod: 0s
  syncPeriod: 0s
ipvs:
  excludeCIDRs: null
  minSyncPeriod: 0s
  scheduler: ""
  strictARP: false
  syncPeriod: 0s
  tcpFinTimeout: 0s
  tcpTimeout: 0s
  udpTimeout: 0s
kind: KubeProxyConfiguration
metricsBindAddress: ""
mode: ""
nodePortAddresses: null
oomScoreAdj: null
portRange: ""
showHiddenMetricsForVersion: ""
udpIdleTimeout: 0s
winkernel:
  enableDSR: false
  networkName: ""
  sourceVip: ""
kubeconfig.conf:
----
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    server: https://10.0.4.16:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    namespace: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
users:
- name: default
  user:
    tokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token

BinaryData
====

Events:  <none>
```

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system exec kube-proxy-gkkxq cat /var/lib/kube-proxy/kubeconfig.conf

kubectl exec [POD] [COMMAND] is DEPRECATED and will be removed in a future version. Use kubectl exec [POD] -- [COMMAND] instead.
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
    server: https://10.0.4.16:6443
  name: default
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: default
    namespace: default
    user: default
  name: default
current-context: default
users:
- name: default
  user:
    tokenFile: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
```

The `mode` [defaults to `iptables`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/config-api/kube-proxy-config.v1alpha1/#kubeproxy-config-k8s-io-v1alpha1-ProxyMode), as the logs above confirm.
I also have IP forwarding enabled on all nodes.

```
$ sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

Comment: It seems there's an issue with subnets: pod network cidr is `10.1.0.0/16` and control plane endpoint is actually within the pod network cidr (since it's `10.1.0.4`). Also did you change `pod network cidr` when you installed `flannel`? By default it uses a different `cidr`.

Comment: I installed flannel like this: `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/v0.16.3/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`. My `kubeadm init` command had the `--pod-network-cidr=10.1.0.0/16` and `--control-plane-endpoint=10.0.4.16` flags set

Comment: You can check what is inside in yaml configuration of flannel. You will see that `"Network": "10.244.0.0/16"` is set to different subnet than you init-ed the cluster with option `--pod-network-cidr=10.1.0.0/16`. You have 2 options to fix it: you can change subnet in yaml of flannel to the same as `--pod-network-cidr=10.1.0.0/16` or you can destroy your cluster and start with the same subnet as in yaml of flannel `"Network": "10.244.0.0/16"`

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick. If you like, you can create an answer and I'll make sure to accept it. And I might subsequently suggest an edit that adds a script to automatically rewrite that YAML file using `yq` and `jq`

Comment: Sure, thank you. My friend @radekw will post the answer for me since he needs some reputation + he gave me that suggestion. Feel free to accept it and suggest an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Flannel](https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel#flannel) can be install by apply a manifest from repository.

> Flannel can be added to any existing Kubernetes cluster though it's simplest to add  `flannel`  before any pods using the pod network have been started.
> For Kubernetes v1.17+  `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml`

As you can see in this `yaml` file by default network subnet is set to `10.244.0.0/16`

```
  net-conf.json: |
    {
      "Network": "10.244.0.0/16",
      "Backend": {
        "Type": "vxlan"
      }
```

`kubeadm init` is a [command](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/) to init a cluster which require specify a subnet for cluster network  and it needs to be the same as subnet in your CNI. You can check for more [options](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-init/#options).

> --pod-network-cidr string
> Specify range of IP addresses for the pod network. If set, the control plane will automatically allocate CIDRs for every node.

You inited a cluster with `--pod-network-cidr=10.1.0.0/16` and subnet of your cluster was set to different than subnet in the yaml file of flannel manifest `"10.244.0.0/16"` and that is why it didn't work.

There are two options to fix it:
First - change subnet in yaml of flannel configuration to the same as it was applied when cluster was init-ed, in this case it's `--pod-network-cidr=10.1.0.0/16` (see script below)
OR
Second - if cluster is for testing purposes and was just init-ed, then destroy a cluster and start with the same subnet as yaml of flannel configuration `"Network": "10.244.0.0/16"`

To automatically modify the `kube-flannel.yml`, the following script based on the [`yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/) and [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) commands can be used:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

input=$1
output=$2

echo "Converting $input to $output"

netconf=$( yq '. | select(.kind == "ConfigMap") | select(.metadata.name == "kube-flannel-cfg") | .data."net-conf.json"' "$input" | jq 'fromjson | .Network="10.1.0.0/16"' | yq -R '.' )
kube_flannel_cfg=$( yq --yaml-output '. | select(.kind == "ConfigMap") | select(.metadata.name == "kube-flannel-cfg") | .data."net-conf.json"='"$netconf" "$input" )
everything_else=$( yq --yaml-output '. | select(.kind != "ConfigMap") | select(.metadata.name != "kube-flannel-cfg")' "$input" )
echo "$kube_flannel_cfg" >> "$output"
echo '---' >> "$output"
echo "$everything_else" >> "$output"
```